# How to active a Toast without button

Tags: javascript, toast, material-design-lite

I work with material desing and i'm working on a form. 
I want when the form was send in the database display a pop-up with a toast.

Documentation: [Toast Material Desing](https://getmdl.io/components/index.html#snackbar-section)

I have try to create a fonction like this:

```
 <script>
        function test() {
            var notification = document.querySelector('.mdl-js-snackbar');
            console.log(notification);
            notification.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(
                {
                    message: 'Image Uploaded'
                }
            );
        }

        test();
 </script>
```

and I have define my snackbar:

```
    <button id="demo-show-toast" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised " type="button" onclick="test()">Show Toast</button>
<div id="demo-toast-example" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
    <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
    <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button" ></button>
</div>
```

I want display the toast on the loading of the page but i catch an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'showSnackbar' of undefined
at test
```

But on the same time i can call the function with the console and it work perfectly.

How can i do for call the toast on the loading of the page and what i have missed? 
Thanks

Comment: Found this [link](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/1995). If using Material Design Lite v1.0.6, SnackBar is not in that version.
Other issue could be "material is not yet loaded or bound to the elements. If you put timeout then it will work."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem is material is not loaded when the function runs,

look this example:

```
<html>
<head>
  <!-- Material Design Lite -->
  <script src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.3.0/material.indigo-pink.min.css">
  <!-- Material Design icon font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
</head>
<body>
  <button id="demo-show-snackbar" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--raised" type="button">Show Snackbar</button>
  <div id="demo-snackbar-example" class="mdl-js-snackbar mdl-snackbar">
    <div class="mdl-snackbar__text"></div>
    <button class="mdl-snackbar__action" type="button"></button>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
    r(function(){
        var notification = document.querySelector('.mdl-js-snackbar');
        notification.MaterialSnackbar.showSnackbar(
          {
            message: 'and..working!!'
          }
        );
    });

    function r(f){/in/.test(document.readyState)?setTimeout('r('+f+')',9):f()}


</script>
```